# T SQL CTE Previous Row Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

I have the below table:

```
SKU     Shop       Week    ShopPrioirty    Replen      Open_Stk  Open_Stk Calc
111     100         1            1           0           17         NULL
111     200         1            2           2           NULL       NULL 
111     300         1            3           0           NULL       NULL
111     400         1            4           0           NULL       NULL

222     100         2            1           5          17          NULL 
222     200         2            2           5          NULL        NULL
222     300         2            3           5          NULL        NULL
222     400         2            4           5          NULL        NULL
```

This is the desired result:

```
SKU     Shop      Week    ShopPrioirty    Replen      Open_Stk  Open_Stk Calc
111     100         1            1           0           17         17
111     200         1            2           2          NULL        17
111     300         1            3           0          NULL        15
111     400         1            4           0          NULL        15

222     100         2            1           20           17        17
222     200         2            2           15          NULL       12
222     300         2            3           12          NULL        7
222     400         2            4           10          NULL        2
```

I need to update the 'Open_Stk Calc' based on the previous row:

```
'Open_Stk Calc' - IIF('Replen'<=IIF('Open_Stk'>=0,'Open_Stk',0),'Replen',0)
```

I am using a CTE to update a row based on a calculation of the previous rows.  This is my SQL:

```
    ;WITH CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT
        SKU,
        [Shop],
        [Week],
        [Store_Priority],
        [Replen],      
        [Open_Stk],
        [Open_Stk Calc],
        FIRST_VALUE([Open_Stk]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [SKU] ,[Week] ORDER BY [Store_Priority] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
        - 
ISNULL(SUM(IIF([Replen] <= IIF([Open_Stk]>=0,[Open_Stk],0),[Replen],0))
        OVER (PARTITION BY [SKU] ,[Week] ORDER BY [Store_Priority] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS CurrentStock
    FROM [tblTEST])

    UPDATE CTE 
    SET [Open_Stk Calc] = CurrentStock
```

However, this produces the following result:

```
SKU     Shop       Week    ShopPrioirty    Replen      Open_Stk  Open_Stk Calc
111     100         1            1           0           17         17
111     200         1            2           2           NULL       17 
111     300         1            3           0           NULL       17
111     400         1            4           0           NULL       17
```

And not the desired result - where have I gone wrong?

Comment: IIF can't use OVER()

Comment: `FIRST_VALUE` only has 1 `OVER` clause; what is the 2nd for? Also, after that, you end that `OVER` with `, 0)`, which closes the CTE definition; so yes, you also have too many parenthesis.

Comment: @Michael: Can you supply the table schema and some test data ?

Comment: @StefanSteiger I have updated with Test data

Comment: Your formula `IIF([Replen] <= IIF([Open_Stk]>=0,[Open_Stk],0),[Replen],0) as [IIF2]`   yields 0 for all the rows of SKU 111. Maybe what you want is, instead of using `Open_stk` in this calculation, to use `Open_Stk Calc`? This will probably need recursion

Answer (score 1):

As one can see in the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the `OVER` clauses supports specific kind of functions:

```
Ranking functions 
Aggregate functions 
Analytic functions 
NEXT VALUE FOR function
```

None of them include `IIF`, as Luis Cazares noted in their comment.

Your code indicates you *do* have a clue about what you are doing - maybe you forgot to put your `IIF` inside a `SUM`?

Comment: yes the sum seems to have fixed it, but it is still not created the desired result as per my recent edit to the original post